# Jenkins: failures due to an extra "%402" character in the location address

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

My runs are failing, I think due to existence of this suspicious character "%402" in the location addresses. When I check the folder name via terminal this folder name does not exist, while it appears in the Jenkins logs. 
I wonder anyone has similar experiences.

Here is a snippet from the error log:

```
Results :

Tests in error: 
  testMultiThreading(edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.edison.annotators.SimpleGazetteerAnnotatorTest): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mangipu2/.jenkins/workspace/cogcomp-nlp%402/edison/target/classes/testgazetteers/names (No such file or directory)
  testAddView(edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.edison.annotators.SimpleGazetteerAnnotatorTest): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mangipu2/.jenkins/workspace/cogcomp-nlp%402/edison/target/classes/testgazetteers/names (No such file or directory)
  testSimpleGazetteerAnnotatorString(edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.edison.annotators.SimpleGazetteerAnnotatorTest): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mangipu2/.jenkins/workspace/cogcomp-nlp%402/edison/target/classes/testgazetteers/names (No such file or directory)
  testNonLazy(edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.edison.annotators.AnnotatorLazyInitTest): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mangipu2/.jenkins/workspace/cogcomp-nlp%402/edison/target/classes/testgazetteers/names (No such file or directory)
  testLazy(edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.edison.annotators.AnnotatorLazyInitTest): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mangipu2/.jenkins/workspace/cogcomp-nlp%402/edison/target/classes/testgazetteers/names (No such file or directory)
```

And the full error log: http://morgoth.cs.illinois.edu:8080/job/cogcomp-nlp/74/console

Answer (score 9):

Edit : Post totally rewrited with the solution.

When you use the "ws" directive in your Jenkinsfile, Jenkins creates multiple workspace folder to execute concurrent build :

- **jobName**_**branch**-**generated_key**@2
- **jobName**_**branch**-**generated_key**@2@tmp
- **jobName**_**branch**-**generated_key**@script

You can get more informations on this [thread](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#allocating-workspaces).

The hexadecimal code for the special character "@" is "%40", so the extra character that you see is in fact this "@2" suffix with the encoded "@".

I've analyzed the source code of Jenkins and see that you can override the default character "@" used to build the suffix.

To solve this problem you just have to add the system property **"-Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList=${new_character}"** when you launch your Jenkins Server.

[Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/slaves/WorkspaceList.java) is the line of code that load the property from system.

Comment: Ah nice; thanks for letting us know. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @Daniel : I don't know if you've been noticed by my post edition. FYI, i was not able to test it yesterday but i tried it today and it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I can see Perforce (P4 Plugin) doesnt like it when there is this @

I am using Amazon Linux so this is what I did to get it working

```
sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
# Added This line
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.timezone=America/Los_Angeles -Dhudson.slaves.WorkspaceList='_'"
```

Comment: Based on this, I edited that line in the Ubuntu service file configuration using: 
`systemctl edit --full jenkins.service`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, but didn't have access to change the Jenkins config. I was able to get it working by manually defining a custom workspace for each sub-stage.

```
stage('stage1'){
  agent {
    node {
      label 'master'
      customWorkspace "${BUILD_TAG}-id"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: works like a charm, however use `master` in the label or your custom node's name.

Comment: @KoustavRay changed it